# MPMoviePlayer - multiple notifications

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to observe playback ended notifications so I can loop the video:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

...

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];

self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object: self.moviePlayer];
- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)note {
    if (note.object == self.moviePlayer) {

        NSInteger reason = [[note.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {
            NSLog(@"THIS HAPPENS FOUR TIMES every time the movie ends");
            [self.moviePlayer play];
        }
    }
}
```

As noted in the comment, I get this notification 4 times every time the video ends. The player still loops, but I don't like that I'm telling it to play 4 times.

Also, if I use MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification instead of MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification I only get notified once. However in that case the movie doesn't loop. This is all because the following doesn't work at all:

```
self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

So my question is why do I get 4 MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded notifications every time the movie ends? Also is there a more foolproof way to loop videos?

Comment: What is your iOS target version for the project ?

Comment: @danypata it is ios5+

Comment: Your video is from local files or from web ? Don't know how is your `theURL` looking so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: it is local, in the main bundle.

Comment: Are you sure that you have registered for that notification only once - make sure you have!